# Can I do pointerarithmetic like this to avoid letting the pointer leave array bounds?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

Imagine code like this:

```
void some_scope()
{
    int OriginPointer[SOME_GIVEN_AMOUNT];
    int *ActingPointer;

    ActingPointer = OriginPointer;

    while ((ActingPointer - OriginPointer) < SOME_GIVEN_AMOUNT)
    {
        *ActingPointer = SOME_ASSIGNMENT;
        ActingPointer++;
    }

    do
    {
        *ActingPointer = 0;
    } while ((ActingPointer != OriginPointer) && (ActingPointer-- != OriginPointer))
}
```

Regarding the fact that the logical branching is by standard ensured to be evaluated from left to right and and says regarding the conditional `&` it breaks as soon as one condition is false, Is there any rule that would make this snippet invalid? I know there are more efficent and even better to retrace ways, but I'm specially interested in:
does the interupt condition of the `do`/`while` loop prevent from invoking undefined behavior through the rule about using pointer arithmetic that results in a pointer leaving the bounds or more as 1 past the array?

Comment: it seems he's only decreasing it. Assuming it ever leaves the endless loop.

Comment: sorry My fault. I forgot to increment the first loop in this snippet, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this loop:

```
while ((ActingPointer - OriginPointer) < SOME_GIVEN_AMOUNT)
{
    *ActingPointer = SOME_ASSIGNMENT;
    ActingPointer++;
}
```

`ActingPointer` ends up being equal to `OriginPointer + SOME_GIVEN_AMOUNT`, which is ok as a pointer (as it points to one element past the end), but writing to it in the first iteration of the `do` loop is undefined behaviour.

If `ActingPointer` is decremented before the `do` loop, everything is fine.

> does the interupt condition of the do/while loop prevent from invoking
>   undefined behavior through the rule about using pointer arithmetic
>   that results in a pointer leaving the bounds or more as 1 past the
>   array?

Yes, because it starts at 1 past the array, and is not decremented below the start of the array.

Comment: Yep the incrementation of the first loop is missing. I added it.

Comment: Ok so the do while foot in my snippet is fine while simply doing `while (ActingPointer-- != OriginPointer)` would be undefined behavior right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because `ActingPointer` would be one below the start of the array, which is UB.

Comment: @Zaibis : it's still wrong if `SOME_GIVEN_AMOUNT` is `0`. Why not `while (ActingPointer > OriginPointer) { ActingPointer--; *ActingPointer = 0; }` ?